# How get car route between two coordinates using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, gmaps4rails, rails-geocoder

I'm developing rails app with google maps and car routes.

I have a start and finish points for car route - two coordinates. How can I get a full car route (array of coordinates for car through streets)? Can I do it using `gmaps4rails` and `geocoder`?

Something like this:

```
start_point = [41,2423; 45,323452]
end_point   = [42,2423; 42,323452]

full_route = some_method_for_calculate_route( start_point, end_point )

#paint line on map from array of points
paint_line( full_route )
```

Please help, 
thanks kindly :)

Comment: you want to display it on a map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it client side, you have a [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0T1i5MrJqiRBUpF8334o?p=preview).

It is highly inspired by the [google documentation here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple).

Basically its a way to interact with google libraries

```
  var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){

    var start_point = [43.2423, 5.323452];
    var end_point   = [44.2423, 5.323452];

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    directionsDisplay.setMap(handler.getMap());
    var request = {
      origin:      new google.maps.LatLng(start_point[0], start_point[1]),
      destination: new google.maps.LatLng(end_point[0], end_point[1]),
      travelMode:  google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use [the Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/). This will return you a JSON Object (or XML) with an array of directions including distance, coordinates, and written instructions.