# How show two lines on map using gmaps4rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

I'm developing rails app, which use google maps and paint car routes.

I use `gmaps4rails` gem for drawling line on a map,

So, I have a plan for car ( array of coordinates for car route by plan ) and report for car ( array of coordinates for car route which was actually drove ).

So, I have to arrays of coordinates - plan and report, example with random points :

```
@plan   = [ [12.124, 12,34253], [11.124, 12,34253], ... [8.124, 5.344] ]
@report = [ [12.224, 12,64253], [10.124, 12,34253], ... [9.124, 6.345] ]
```

I know how draw one line on map, for example this is view with 'plan' line on map:

```
%div.container
  %div.panel.panel-default.col-sm-9
    %div.panel-body.row
      #map.col-sm-12

:javascript
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    polyline = #{raw @plan.to_json}

    handler.addPolyline(polyline); // and not addPolylines
    handler.bounds.extend(polyline[0]);
    handler.bounds.extend(polyline[ polyline.length - 1]);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
  });
```

But now I need to draw 'plan' line and 'report' line on the same map.
How can I draw two lines with different colors on the same map?

Thanks kindly.

Comment: whats the resulting html please? (so I can create a plunkr)

Comment: and please provide the other routes

Comment: @apneadiving I have two arrays with coordinates (plan and report), resulting html is one map with two lines - the same as my example with haml view. I just don't know how draw two lines and set color of line - it needs js changes...

Comment: @apneadiving, thank you for any html example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your code, gmaps4rails expects an array of objects providing `lat` and `lng` properties. The transformation is quite easy though.

Concerning the options, you can pass them as a second argument. [Source code](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/gmaps/google/builders/polyline.coffee) is meant to be very clear.

Anyway, [Here is a working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/l2F8abz88vVyNY2ZOste?p=preview) with your data

Comment: thanks a lot fro example! ( maybe you can help me with one other similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27017658/how-get-car-route-between-two-coordinates-using-ruby )